# Rotate axis label in Swift Charts

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

I'm using Swift Charts in a SwiftUI app to make a line chart. I would like to rotate the Y axis label such that it reads from bottom to top. I tried to rotate the text but the rotation causes the label to not render properly. Is there a way to rotate the axis label?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {

    struct Point: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let x: Float
        let y: Float
    }

    let points = [
        Point(x: 0, y: 1),
        Point(x: 1, y: 4.5),
        Point(x: 2, y: 3),
        Point(x: 3, y: 6),
        Point(x: 4, y: 7),
        Point(x: 5, y: 5.2),
        Point(x: 6, y: 9),
        Point(x: 7, y: 12.5),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(points) { point in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("X values", point.x),
                    y: .value("Y values", point.y)
                )
            }
        }
        .chartXAxisLabel("The x-axis", alignment: .center)
        .chartYAxisLabel(position: .leading) {
            Text("The y-axis")
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
        }
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .leading)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 300)
    }
}
```

The window produced from the example is shown below. Notice, the label for the Y axis does not display properly.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This issue seems to be caused by the space the label requires.

For example by adding the line `.frame(minWidth: 55, minHeight: 50)` to the rotated text, the issue gets solved (however, the label requires a lot of space, which I was not able to solve).

Updated chartYAxisLabel code:

```
 .chartYAxisLabel(position: .leading) {
                Text("The y-axis")
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
                    .frame(minWidth: 55, minHeight: 50)
        }
```

Updated preview:

[image: updated graph])

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming late to the party, but I post my solution for future references.

For iOS 16 and later, one can use the `Layout` protocol to correctly size rotated text. With this, you can define a custom text modifier that allows rotating without sizing inconsistencies (and without setting a size manually, which produces blank spaces):

```
//  VerticalLayout.swift
//
// Layout to keep the correct size for vertically rotated text
//

import SwiftUI

private struct VerticalLayout: Layout {
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let size = subviews.first!.sizeThatFits(.unspecified)
        return .init(width: size.height, height: size.width)
    }

    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        subviews.first!.place(at: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), anchor: .center, proposal: .unspecified)
    }
}

private struct RotatedContent: ViewModifier {
    let angle: Angle
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        VerticalLayout(){
            content
        }
        .rotationEffect(angle)
    }
}

extension View {
    func rotate(_ angle: Angle) -> some View {
        self.modifier(RotatedContent(angle: angle))
    }
}
```

This can then be used as `Text("Your text").rotate(.degrees(270))` to rotate the Text element. However, when inserting this in the `.chartYAxisLabel`, the text still doesn't render correctly.

To solve this further problem and display the y axis label as desired, one can then use an `HStack` to display the legend separately from the Chart:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack(alingment: .center, spacing: 8){
        // Insert the Y axis label, changing the size and style to match
        // regular axis labels
        Text(yAxisLabel)
            .font(.caption2)
            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
            .rotate(.degrees(-90))
    
        Chart{
            // ... Your Chart content 
        }
        // ... The options for the Chart, without .chartYAxisLabel, 
        // as we already rendered it
    }

}
```

This results in something like this:

[image: example chart]

Of course, it would be nice to have an easier way to do this...or to have the y axis on the left and correctly rotated by default, as that is the standard representation.